# Access multi-dimentional Array

Tags: java, arrays

array :

```
public static String[][] dhaka_header = {
        {"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"}, 
        {"b", "b", "b", "b", "b"}, 
        {"c", "c", "c"},
};
```

How can I access each array element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a 2-dimensional array: `array[rows][cols]`.

You can access each member of your array with nested `for` like so:

```
for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
        array[row][col] = "0"; // whatever you want goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Two-Dimensional array

```
String[][] sa1 = new String[4][5];
for( int i = 0; i < sa1.length; i++) {           // sa1.length == 4
    for ( int j = 0; j < sa1[i].length; j++) {   // sa1[i].length == 5
        sa1[i][j] = "new String value";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way is using foreach loop.

```
String[][] dhaka_header = {
        {"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"},
        {"b", "b", "b", "b", "b"},
        {"c", "c", "c"},
};

for (String[] rowValues : dhaka_header) {
    for (String value : rowValues) {
        System.out.println(value); // or something else
    }
}
```

or `streams` if you can use `java8`. Below two examples.

First using double `foreach`

```
Arrays.stream(dhaka_header)
        .forEach(rowValues -> Arrays.stream(rowValues)
                .forEach(value -> System.out.print(value))
        );
```

and second using `flatmap` to flatten arrays to one dimension and then `foreach` to perform some action on each element

```
Arrays.stream(dhaka_header)
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .forEach(value -> System.out.print(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implements nested for loops for rows and columns as below,

```
 class mapping
  {
      public static String[][] dhaka_header = {
      {"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"}, 
      {"b", "b", "b", "b", "b"}, 
      {"c", "c", "c"},
  };
 }
 public class Testarr 
   {

 public static void main(String arg[])
     {
     mapping obj=new mapping();
        // outer loop for accessing rows
        for(int i=0;i<obj.dhaka_header.length;i++)
        {
        // inner loop for accessing cols
           for (int j=0;j<obj.dhaka_header[i].length;j++)
            {
            System.out.print(obj.dhaka_header[i][j]+" ");
            }
           System.out.println("");
        }
    }
 }
    // here is outputs looks like
a a a a a a a  
b b b b b  
c c c
```